# Use two models in 1 view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

So I got this signup page where I want to make users be able to log in using Facebook.
I got the code for it but in the view im already using my @model SignInModel but I want to use
@model ICollection

any ideas how this is possible?

Comment: well we do have ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a new model, something like:

```
public class CompositeModel
{
    public ICollection Collection {get; set; }

    public SignInModel SignInModel {get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a base model that contains the models you need for the view:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public ICollection Collection {get; set; }
    public SignInModel SignInModel {get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model Project.Models.BaseModel
```

Comment: But if I do like that I cant get the properties from each model?

Comment: Of course you can - to access a property it would look like this in your view: `@model.SignInModel.FooProperty`... simple